# WinJS getFolderAsync with path parameter

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

So the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.getfolderasync) for StorageFolder.GetFolderAsync says that the String parameter can be the name or the path relative to the current folder of the sub-folder to retrieve.

I can get the name to work just fine, but not the relative paths, e.g. for "localFolder/myFolder/mySubFolder/":

```
localFolder.getFolderAsync("myFolder/mySubFolder" or "/myFolder/mySubFolder").done( /* Your success and error handlers */ );
```

It works just fine if I chain getFolderAsync("myFolder") and getFolderAsync("mySubFolder").

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add path like "Screenshots\Screenshot (3).png"
example:

```
 localFolder.getFolderAsync("Screenshots\\Screenshot (3).png").done()
```

Comment: I'm trying to get a folder, not a file.

Comment: What suganthi is saying is use \\ instead of / for your relatve paths. I tested this with your code: "myFolder/mySubfolder" will fail but "myFolder\\mySubfolder" succeeds. This is just making sure to use pathname \'s (which need \\ escaping) rather than URI /'s.

Comment: Right, I this totally tripped my up because of those normal-slashed URI's.... Belated thanks!